# Live streaming Audio from iOS

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, core-audio

I have tried to live stream audio (AAC-LC) from iOS for 3 months without much success...

- I tried Audio Queues, which work well but there is a strange delay (~4s) and I don't know why (high level API ?)
- I tried Audio Units, it sometimes works on the simulator but never with the phone using a modified code from [this source](http://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/en/bf/amm/produkte/audiocodec/audiocodecs/aaceld.html)

I am really lost, can anyone help me ?

EDIT
I have to do a live streaming application (iPhone-> Wowza Server via RTSP). The video part works well with little delay (1s). Now I'm trying to add audio in addition to video but I'm stuck with the SDK.

tldr : I need to capture microphone input then send AAC frames over the network without getting huge delay

Comment: Without knowledge of the application and site of your code, chances of help are slim.   I suggest improving your question.

Comment: I edited a bit, hope it can help

Answer (score 1):

This app, which I just now completed, broadcasts audio between any two iOS devices on the same network:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tKgVl0X92SYvgpvbljRzilXNQ6iBcjqM

Compile it with the latest beta release of Xcode 9, and run it on two iOS 11 (beta) devices.

The app is simple; you launch it, and then start talking. Everything is automatic, from network connectivity to audio streaming.

Events generated by the app are displayed in an event log in the app:

[image]

Even though the code is simple and concise, the event log was provided to make understanding the app's architecture quicker and more easily.

Comment: Thanks, even though it's quite old for me - and I never made it works "production ready" - I will take a look at your code :)

Comment: Definitely let me know your results; streaming two-way audio, live, is difficult with any of the frameworks available to developers. I believe this to be intentional; it keeps developers from competing with FaceTime, and from providing alternatives to major carriers. Knowing how hard it is and the reasons for it, I'd be really suspicious of a job requirement that said I had to put together a "production ready" telecom system for iPhone. It sounds uninformed, because it's unrealistic.

Comment: For some reason when I open this app on two different devices, each device streams itself, not each other as I expected. What could be wrong? Also do you update the project, or release it?